# USB WIFI Realtek not an MTP device

Tags: wireless, usb, realtek, mtp

I bought the LOTEKOO USB Wireless Network Adapter, Powerful 5dBi Antenna 600Mbps Dual Band from amazon. I been trying to get it to work with my Ubuntu: "Linux 4.15.0-34-generic #37~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Tue Aug 28 10:44:06 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux". First I compiled and installed the drivers per [instructions on GitHub](https://github.com/gnab/rtl8812au/issues/144).
But when I insert the USB Dongle is not detected. 
Looking at syslog:

```
Nov  3 14:50:23 pluto mtp-probe: bus: 3, device: 20 was not an MTP device
Nov  3 14:51:49 pluto kernel: [ 1795.291025] usb 3-4: USB disconnect, device number 20
Nov  3 14:51:51 pluto kernel: [ 1797.327114] usb 3-4: new high-speed USB device number 21 using xhci_hcd
Nov  3 14:51:52 pluto kernel: [ 1797.475703] usb 3-4: New USB device found, idVendor=0bda, idProduct=c811
Nov  3 14:51:52 pluto kernel: [ 1797.475709] usb 3-4: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
Nov  3 14:51:52 pluto kernel: [ 1797.475712] usb 3-4: Product: 802.11ac NIC
Nov  3 14:51:52 pluto kernel: [ 1797.475715] usb 3-4: Manufacturer: Realtek
Nov  3 14:51:52 pluto kernel: [ 1797.475718] usb 3-4: SerialNumber: 123456
Nov  3 14:51:52 pluto mtp-probe: checking bus 3, device 21: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-4"
Nov  3 14:51:52 pluto mtp-probe: bus: 3, device: 21 was not an MTP device
Nov  3 14:51:52 pluto kernel: [ 1797.726714] usb 3-4: USB disconnect, device number 21
Nov  3 14:51:52 pluto kernel: [ 1798.035116] usb 3-4: new high-speed USB device number 22 using xhci_hcd
Nov  3 14:51:52 pluto kernel: [ 1798.183466] usb 3-4: New USB device found, idVendor=0bda, idProduct=c811
Nov  3 14:51:52 pluto kernel: [ 1798.183472] usb 3-4: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
Nov  3 14:51:52 pluto kernel: [ 1798.183475] usb 3-4: Product: 802.11ac NIC
Nov  3 14:51:52 pluto kernel: [ 1798.183479] usb 3-4: Manufacturer: Realtek
Nov  3 14:51:52 pluto kernel: [ 1798.183482] usb 3-4: SerialNumber: 123456
Nov  3 14:51:52 pluto mtp-probe: checking bus 3, device 22: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-4"
Nov  3 14:51:52 pluto mtp-probe: bus: 3, device: 22 was not an MTP device
```

Following some instructions I created a udev rules files:

```
db2admin@pluto:/etc/udev/rules.d$ cat 90-myrules.rules 
SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0bda", ATTRS{idProduct}=="c811", ATTRS{serial}=="123456"
```

When I look at the output of:

```
udevadm monitor --udev --property
```

UDEV  [1662.908962] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-4 (usb)
ACTION=remove
BUSNUM=003
DEVNAME=/dev/bus/usb/003/019
DEVNUM=019
DEVPATH=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-4
DEVTYPE=usb_device
ID_BUS=usb
ID_MODEL=802.11ac_NIC
ID_MODEL_ENC=802.11ac\x20NIC
ID_MODEL_ID=c811
ID_REVISION=0200
ID_SERIAL=Realtek_802.11ac_NIC_123456
ID_SERIAL_SHORT=123456
ID_USB_INTERFACES=:ffffff:
ID_VENDOR=Realtek
ID_VENDOR_ENC=Realtek
ID_VENDOR_FROM_DATABASE=Realtek Semiconductor Corp.
ID_VENDOR_ID=0bda
MAJOR=189
MINOR=274
PRODUCT=bda/c811/200
SEQNUM=7598
SUBSYSTEM=usb
TYPE=0/0/0
USEC_INITIALIZED=1648553212

```
UDEV  [1710.433564] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-4/3-4:1.0 (usb)
.MM_USBIFNUM=00
ACTION=add
DEVPATH=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-4/3-4:1.0
DEVTYPE=usb_interface
ID_VENDOR_FROM_DATABASE=Realtek Semiconductor Corp.
INTERFACE=255/255/255
MODALIAS=usb:v0BDApC811d0200dc00dsc00dp00icFFiscFFipFFin00
PRODUCT=bda/c811/200
SEQNUM=7619
SUBSYSTEM=usb
TYPE=0/0/0
USEC_INITIALIZED=1709427721
```

output of `sudo lshw -C network`:

```
USB

  *-network DISABLED
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Wireless 7260
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:06:00.0
       logical name: wlp6s0
       version: 6b
       serial: e8:b1:fc:50:1f:c7
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=4.15.0-34-generic firmware=17.608620.0 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:36 memory:f7900000-f7901fff
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       physical id: 2
       bus info: usb@3:3
       logical name: wlx503eaa53e6ba
       serial: 50:3e:aa:53:e6:ba
       capabilities: ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=r8188eu ip=192.168.1.165 multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
```

does not show my third network device just the two that I have and work.

The command:

```
 lsusb
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8008 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 005: ID 8087:07dc Intel Corp. 
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 06cb:0ac3 Synaptics, Inc. 
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 0bda:c811 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 0bda:8179 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTL8188EUS 802.11n Wireless Network Adapter
Bus 003 Device 006: ID 0bda:573c Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

shows my device which is 0bda:c811 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. the second realtek device is another USB Wifi that is working but is not 5G.

```
sudo lshw -C network
  *-network DISABLED

       description: Wireless interface
       product: Wireless 7260
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:06:00.0
       logical name: wlp6s0
       version: 6b
       serial: e8:b1:fc:50:1f:c7
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=4.15.0-34-generic firmware=17.608620.0 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:36 memory:f7900000-f7901fff
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       physical id: 2
       bus info: usb@3:3
       logical name: wlx503eaa53e6ba
       serial: 50:3e:aa:53:e6:ba
       capabilities: ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=r8188eu ip=192.168.1.165 multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
```

I wondering what I am i missing. Thanks for any help provided.

Comment: What results for `mokutil --sb-state`

Comment: rtl8812au is not correct for this device: "New USB device found, idVendor=0bda, idProduct=c811" Possibly helpful: https://github.com/whitebatman2/rtl8821CU Like my colleague @Jeremy31 , I am wondering why you are not able to use the built-in Intel which should easily outperform any USB device, especially one for which there is ony an obscure driver that needs to be compiled from source code.

Comment: @Jeremy31 Not sure what this means but here is the output of mokutil db2admin@pluto:~$ mokutil --sb-state
EFI variables are not supported on this system

Comment: @chili555 Well I feel kind of silly. I am not sure why that answer never pop up on my searches before (wasted so much time) but it worked! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

This answer should be credited to @chili555 who gave the correct answer in his comment above. For others that might be struggling with this here are the steps:
First enable/install dkms.

```
sudo apt-get install dkms
```

Then here is the sequence of commands I followed:

```
sudo apt-get install dkms
cd Downloads/
git clone https://github.com/whitebatman2/rtl8821CU.git
cd rtl8821CU/
export DRV_NAME=rtl8821CU
export DRV_VERSION=5.2.5.3
set |grep DRV
sudo mkdir /usr/src/${DRV_NAME}-${DRV_VERSION}
git archive master | sudo tar -x -C /usr/src/${DRV_NAME}-${DRV_VERSION}
cd rtl8821CU/
git archive master | sudo tar -x -C /usr/src/${DRV_NAME}-${DRV_VERSION}
sudo dkms add -m ${DRV_NAME} -v ${DRV_VERSION}
sudo dkms build -m ${DRV_NAME} -v ${DRV_VERSION}
sudo dkms install -m ${DRV_NAME} -v ${DRV_VERSION}
```

Answer (score 0):

Updated @chili555's and @Fabio's answer for 2023 (GitHub's default root changed from "master" to "main") and removed duplicate lines.

```
    sudo apt-get install dkms
    cd Downloads/
    git clone https://github.com/whitebatman2/rtl8821CU.git
    cd rtl8821CU
    export DRV_NAME=rtl8821CU
    export DRV_VERSION=5.2.5.3
    set |grep DRV
    sudo mkdir /usr/src/${DRV_NAME}-${DRV_VERSION}
    git archive main | sudo tar -x -C /usr/src/${DRV_NAME}-${DRV_VERSION}
    sudo dkms add -m ${DRV_NAME} -v ${DRV_VERSION}
    sudo dkms build -m ${DRV_NAME} -v ${DRV_VERSION}
    sudo dkms install -m ${DRV_NAME} -v ${DRV_VERSION}
```