# Wi-Fi adapter realtek 802.11ac not working on Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS, tried everything :(

Tags: wireless, 20.04, realtek

I installed Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS and wi-fi adapter - realtek 802.11ac doesn't work :(
It used to work on older Ubuntu I had a while ago...
I tried  probably every link from  2 first pages of google and a lot of questions asked here  and spend hours no solution worked.... Maybe someone has a solution to my problem?

```
lshw -C network 
  *-network                 
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:08:00.0
       logical name: enp8s0
       version: 15
       serial: a8:a1:59:22:3c:32
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 firmware=rtl8168h-2_0.0.2 02/26/15 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII
       resources: irq:24 ioport:d000(size=256) memory:fca04000-fca04fff memory:fca00000-fca03fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 1
       bus info: usb@1:2
       logical name: usb0
       serial: 6e:af:3c:18:aa:8a
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rndis_host driverversion=22-Aug-2005 firmware=RNDIS device ip=192.168.37.165 link=yes multicast=yes
WARNING: output may be incomplete or inaccurate, you should run this program as super-user.
```

and

```
lsusb
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 046d:c53f Logitech, Inc. USB Receiver
**Bus 003 Device 003: ID 0bda:c811 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 802.11ac NIC**
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 4b42:6067 KBDFans KBD67v2
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 2109:0815 VIA Labs, Inc. USB3.0 Hub             
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 0bda:8771 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. Bluetooth Radio
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0bda:c811 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 802.11ac NIC
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0c76:161e JMTek, LLC. USB PnP Audio Device
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 04e8:6864 Samsung Electronics Co., Ltd GT-I9070 (network tethering, USB debugging enabled)
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 2109:2815 VIA Labs, Inc. USB2.0 Hub         
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

I don't know what to do - I can't run a ethernet cable to my PC and can't do usb tathering because I'm already using my phone for webcam and microphone to attend my lectures...
Can anyone help?

Comment: Please see: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1162974/wireless-usb-adapter-0bdac811-realtek-semiconductor-corp I am voting to close as a duplicate. Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.