# How to install wifi driver for Dual band USB Adapter

Tags: usb

Seeking your help on how to install the driver of Dual band USB Adapter.  I followed the following steps but got no luck.

sudo apt update

sudo apt install --reinstall build-essential dkms git

git clone https://github.com/cilynx/rtl88x2bu.git

cd ./rtl88x2bu/

sudo rsync -rvhP ./ /usr/src/rtl88x2bu-${VER}

xuser@xcomputer:~/Downloads/rtl88x2bu$ sudo dkms add -m rtl88x2bu -v ${VER}
Error! Invalid number of arguments passed.
Usage: add / or
add -m / or
add -m  -v

#Remaining steps that I haven't done yet.#

sudo dkms build -m rtl88x2bu -v ${VER}
sudo dkms install -m rtl88x2bu -v ${VER}
sudo modprobe 88x2bu

I'm new in Ubuntu and just got installed this version 18.04.

Thank you in advance!
Regards,

J0m$

Comment: If you install 20.04 you may not need to install a driver.

Comment: I need 18.04 version for Amazon workspaces. on 20.04 version, worksaces still not supported. :(

Comment: Boy are they behind 21.04 comes out April of this year.

Comment: I got this solution and now my usb adapter is working well.  See below link.

https://askubuntu.com/questions/1162974/wireless-usb-adapter-0bdac811-realtek-semiconductor-corp