# “Module 88212cu not found” installing rtl8821CU USB driver for 0bda:c811 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 802.11ac NIC wifi adaptor

Tags: wireless, usb, realtek

I'm trying to follow [the steps in this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1163018/204161) to make [this USB wi-fi adaptor](https://www.cclonline.com/product/288570/NPEVO-AC600USB/Wireless-Adapters/Evo-Labs-AC600-Dual-Band-USB-WiFi-Network-Adapter/NET3590/) work on my Ubuntu 20.04 laptop, but get an error message.

This is how the device has been detected by the system:

```
$ lsusb | grep 802
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 0bda:c811 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 802.11ac NIC
```

Other answers on here indicate that the above ID means I want the `rtl8821CU` driver. This apparently builds and installs fine:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/brektrou/rtl8821CU.git
$ cd rtl8821CU
$ sudo ./dkms-install.sh
About to run dkms install steps...

Creating symlink /var/lib/dkms/rtl8821CU/5.4.1/source ->
                 /usr/src/rtl8821CU-5.4.1

DKMS: add completed.

Kernel preparation unnecessary for this kernel.  Skipping...

Building module:
cleaning build area...
'make' KVER=5.4.0-66-generic.....................................................
cleaning build area...

DKMS: build completed.

8821cu.ko:
Running module version sanity check.
 - Original module
   - No original module exists within this kernel
 - Installation
   - Installing to /lib/modules/5.4.0-66-generic/updates/dkms/

depmod....

DKMS: install completed.
Finished running dkms install steps.
```

But then at the final step, it can't be found:

```
$ sudo modprobe 88212cu
modprobe: FATAL: Module 88212cu not found in directory /lib/modules/5.4.0-66-generic
```

What should I try next? Thank you.

Comment: Why `88212cu`? It is `8821cu`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should type commands a bit more carefully.

The module name is `8821cu`.

Comment: Really? Pffft. Several hours into trying to get this to work, and I failed with a stupid typo at the end. Bah. Thank you so much for spotting that so quickly — I will accept your answer as soon as Stack Exchange lets me.