# USB Wifi adapter not working on Ubuntu 20.04 though working on Windows

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, usb, adapter

I got a bluetooth + wifi adapter, when plugged into Ubuntu 20.04, the bluetooth works but wifi adapter is not found. Any ideas on how to resolve this?

The adapter I got is https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B08GSBYX66/ref=ewc_pr_img_1?smid=A23LZ1Z0HGM689&psc=1

Also I'm using windows + ubuntu dual boot.

If you need extra information please ask me!

Comment: Search for  RTL8821CU ubuntu, see what you find

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Wireless USB Adapter 0bda:c811 Realtek Semiconductor Corp](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1162974/wireless-usb-adapter-0bdac811-realtek-semiconductor-corp).  Specifically: https://askubuntu.com/a/1163018

Comment: @Jeremy31 Am I supposed to install this? https://github.com/brektrou/rtl8821CU .
Is that the correct driver for the adapter? I don't understand what rtl8821CU means....