# WIFI stick not working/recognizing wifi

Tags: drivers, wireless, usb, realtek-wireless

I recently added Ubuntu (22.04.1 LTS) as a dual boot to my windows 11 pc.

Now I have the problem that I can't access the internet because I can't find  drivers for this wifi stick.(it says driver free, but that seems to be incorrect because there were drivers for windows)

The stick is:
https://www.amazon.de/dp/B07LFC7VDC?ref=ppx_pop_mob_ap_share

`lsusb` lists the device as `0bda:c811 Realtek Corp. 802.11ac NIC` if that helps

I'm pretty new to ubuntu and linux in general

If you need further info ask in the comments.

Comment: Please post the FULL line that `lsusb` outputs. The ID is essential.

Comment: That is the full line, I found some drivers on a site but I am not sure how to install them without Wifi I think I will try to do this with ethernet if there's no easier solution.
Do I haveto edit the command to find this ID and can you give me an example ID so I know what it looks like.

Comment: This is not a full line.There is ID that you didn't post.

Comment: Drivers from a site are unlikely to work.

Comment: Yeah sorry I overlooked the Id because I thought it was a timestamp, edited the post to include the ID. I meant some github repositorys with drivers from a site, but as I said I'm pretty new to linux and I'm also not sure if those would work so I asked here.

Comment: @trondhansen like pilot said it's a different device, but I found another post talking about a wifi card with the same ID: https://askubuntu.com/a/1163018/1630946
I will try this approach with ethernet later.

Comment: That's a perfect existing answer.

Comment: Oh good then I will use that one, thank you for your help!

Comment: I wrote almost the same as an answer, because I couldn't find that one.

Comment: How does this website work, do I have to delete the post when I found a solution or can I mark it somehow?

Comment: You can click the check sign left from the answer and accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your device is rtl8811cu. You can install drivers this way.

Connect to the internet using Ethernet or your phone and run in a terminal:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install git dkms
git clone https://github.com/brektrou/rtl8821CU.git
cd rtl8821CU
sudo ./dkms-install.sh
```

Comment: Thank you very much!